# #juju- how to copy files from one juju machine to another juju machine?

Tags: juju

I need to copy db `jar` file from one juju machine to another machine.

I tried using `scp` but its not working.

```
ubuntu@charm1-local-machine-4:~$ sudo scp test.txt ubuntu@10.0.3.110:/home/ubuntu
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

I get above error. Please, can any one help on this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the machines do not have ssh access to the other machines.

You probably need to use the client machine as an intermediary.

So use 'juju scp' to copy the file to the client from one machine, then another 'juju scp' to copy from the client to the other machine.